# SQL Try..Catch..Finally Errors Not Displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sqlexception

How can I get the SQLException error messages below to display?

I have a site where users upload a data file. I have intentionally added incorrect data (text to a field that only allows integers) as a test of my error handling. Nothing is rendering in the view. I am sure that an exception is being thrown, as none of the data is in the database. If I remove the incorrect field, everything uploads fine. I have also tried both ex.toString() and ex.message with no success.

In my view, I have:

```
 @ViewBag.ErrorMessage
```

Controller:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql2, con))
{
    try
    {
        // long SQL statement 

        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        TempData["shortMessage"] = "Dataset Uploaded Successfully.";
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the debugger to check whether an exception is being thrown/caught?

Comment: Why the two catches if you are going to do the same thing in each? While i you should be catching the most specific error to be thrown, adding the broad Exception catch makes this SqlException catch worthless.

Comment: If this is a form validation error, it's not going to throw an exception it's going to set the ModelState to invalid.  Responses with validation errors are still Http 200 responses.  You need to check if the ModelState is invalid and return to the view.  Please provide, your viewmodel, view code and controller action.

Comment: Your action method in the given controller is not returning any view. Simply say "return View()" and it will work fine.